S3 bucket policy creation
I am having two ec2 instances(instanceA and instanceB) attached to same IAM role. I need to configure a s3 bucket policy so that, instanceA is able to access the bucket and for instanceB, access should be denied.
The below rule is not working.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowInstanceAAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::211125774119:role/s3-it-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::classic",
                "arn:aws:s3:::classic/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "xxxxx"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAccessFromOthers",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::211125774119:role/s3-it-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::classic",
                "arn:aws:s3:::classic/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "xxxxxxxx"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

help me to write the correct policy.

When you say "not working", what happens for Instance A and what happens for Instance B? Do both instances exist in a public subnet with different public IP addresses assigned, or are they behind a NAT Gateway? How is the bucket being access from the instances -- for example, is it via the AWS CLI, an app using an AWS SDK, or via a web browser? Please Edit your Question to add these additional details.

Not working means, i am able to download the files in s3. not able to restrict the access to s3 from instanceB(even after using the "NotIpAddress" condition in the policy ). yes , both instances exist in a public subnet with different public IP addresses assigned, i am using the aws cli.

Is there a VPC Endpoint for S3 in your subnet? If so, it would probably be communicating via a private IP address rather than the public IP address.
